# What is the relation between physical theory and physical law?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Gravitational law was explained by Newtons theory of gravity. So a law was described by a theory. What is the theory for [Newton's laws of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion)?

Answer (score 2):

The laws *are* the theory. Newton did not explain *why* the gravitational force is $GMm/r^2$. He theorized this formula, and showed that it explained the solar system and apples falling from trees.

Similarly his three laws of motion, plus some assumptions about absolute space and time, *are* the theory of Newtonian mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

Laws, postulates, principles are the the axioms used in physics mathematical models to pick up from the mathematical solutions those that describe data and measurements an predict new situations successfully, validating the theory. As in mathematics one cannot question the axioms, so in physics mathematical models the laws are assumed axiomatically.

As in mathematics, what is a theorem can become an axiom in a different formulation and the axiom becomes the theorem, this can also happen with the physics models allowing different mathematical formulations, which have to be consistent between them.